# Load content from files (and sometimes parse) in Sapper

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making my first Sapper app and the pages are all in routes. I am now extracting the content into a separate directory and unsure if I'm doing anything right.

Here is an excerpt from my directory structure:

```
content
|- index.md
|- services.txt
|- about
   |- index.md
   |- technologies.html
routes
|- index.html
|- services.html
|- section-[section].json.js
|- about
   |- index.html
   |- technologies.html
```

I've made JSON interface `section-[section].json.js` that is used to request content. The content of `sectionX` can be in file `content/sectionX.ext` with whatever extension and the content is also parsed through `marked` if it's a `.md` file.

This is how I am loading the content in my `routes/services.html`:

```
<script>
export default {
    preload() {
        return this.fetch('section-services.json').then(r => r.json()).then(section => {
            return {section};
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Nested files are requested using dot notation, i.e. `about.technologies` could be resolved either to file `content/about/technologies.ext` or `content/about/technologies/index.ext` (similar to how sapper resolves URIs to files).

The part that I would like to have reviewed is my `routes/section-[section].json.js`. This is the file that receives a section name (with slashes replaced by dots) and returns the content, parsed if it's markdown.

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import marked from 'marked'

function getFileFromDir(file, directory)
{
    const filesInDir = fs.readdirSync('content/'+directory, {withFileTypes: true})
                        .filter(f => f.isFile() && file == path.parse(f.name).name)

    if (filesInDir.length)
    {
        let fileName = 'content/'

        if (directory.length)
            fileName += directory + '/'

        fileName += filesInDir[0].name

        return fileName
    }

    return null
}

function getFile(path) 
{
    path = path.split('.')

    // First try to get the named file
    let file = getFileFromDir(path[path.length-1], path.slice(0,-1).join('/'))
    if (file)
        return file

    // Assume that path is a directory and look for index
    file = getFileFromDir('index', path.join('/'))
    if (file)
        return file

    return null
}

export function get(req, res) {
    let file = getFile(req.params.section)

    if (!file)
        return 'Failed to fetch content of section ' + req.params.section

    let content = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')

    if ('.md' == path.extname(file))
        content = marked(content)

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': `max-age=${30 * 60 * 1e3}`
    })

    content = JSON.stringify({content})

    res.end(content)
}
```

My experience with Node is also fairly limited, all tips are appreciated!